# What does "I was almost busted" mean? Thanks

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm watching " Younger", an American drama, Season 1 Episode 1, 15:29. Thanks in advance.

Ms. A: Let me ask you something, you've seen a lot of vaginas, right?

Ms. B: Hmm, I've seen my fair share.

Ms. A: So What's in style?

Ms. B: Why do you ask?

Ms. A: Well, last night at the gym, `I was almost busted` when I was changing. Apparently nobody under 30 looks a day over 12 down there.

Comment: The idiom "almost busted" can mean "almost caught doing something wrong or sneaky" or (as in this case) "almost exposed." In fact, in this example you might have swapped in another idiom: "I almost blew my cover." The basis of the exposure in this case evidently has to do with differences in personal grooming styles among older and younger women in the United States.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the reference to looking a day over 12, she seems to be referring to most women there showing shaved nether regions and her being out of place. Saying she was "almost busted" means she is unshaven and felt out of place comparatively and wants to match with whatever is "in style".

Comment: Ms. A is trying to hide her real age, 40 and now pretending 26. Would you say "was almost busted" is almost discovered or caught?

Comment: She's afraid of being caught being out of style; everyone else is shaved down there, and she is not.  A younger person who is unaware of the current trend would be just as "busted."